# Get Cognito user pool identity in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a Lambda function handling POST requests triggered by the API Gateway.  The latter is set up to authorize via a Cognito user pool authorizer.  Authorization works - if I pass a user's ID token, the request is processed, if I don't I get a 401.

However, I can't get the authorized user's identity in the Lambda function.  All documentation makes me believe that it should be in the context, but it isn't.  I can't map it in there, either.  What's more, there doesn't seem to be a way to query the user pool for a user given their ID token, either.

Do I need an identity pool to accomplish this?  If so, how does that work?  And why wouldn't the API gateway automatically pass on the user's identity?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It depends on if you have `Use Lambda Proxy Integration` selected in the `Integration Request` for the lambda. If you have it set then all the token's claims will be passed through on `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims`.

If you are not using Lambda Proxy Integration then you need to use a `Body Mapping Template` in the `Integration Request` for the lambda. An example template with the `application/json` Content-Type is:

```
"context" : {
    "sub" : "$context.authorizer.claims.sub",
    "username" : "$context.authorizer.claims['cognito:username']",
    "email" : "$context.authorizer.claims.email",
    "userId" : "$context.authorizer.claims['custom:userId']"
}
```

This is expecting that there is a custom attribute called userId in the User Pool of course, and they are readable by the client.

You cannot use the id token against the aws cognito-idp APIs, you need to use the access token. You can however use AdminGetUser call with the username, if your lambda is authorized.

Comment: +1 Also works in python except event is a dictionary and each key listed above needs to be accessed as a dictionary key.

Comment: for some reason $context.authorizer.claims.email always returns null. I do see value being passed for sub. Any pointers?

Comment: if I enable "Lambda Proxy Integration" I can't get CORS to work, no matter what, I get CORS errors in my webapp. Why is that?

Comment: @Paul the return value of Lambda is considered as response and that should allow the origin not API Gateway

Comment: To whom it may concern: you need to make a new deployment in order for changes to the integration mapping template to really take effect. I had to comment things out of my cloud formation template in order to persuade cloud formation to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub` to get user's Cognito identity `sub`, which is basically their ID. *This assumes you're using Proxy Integration with API Gateway and Lambda.*

Here's a simple example using Node; should be similar across other SDKs.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let cognitoIdentity = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub

    // do something with `cognitoIdentity` here

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },        
        body: JSON.stringify("some data for user"),
    };
    return response;
};
```