# Get user attributes from Cognito User Pool through lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I've created a lambda that retrieves user attributes as (username, email, name...etc) however, I wonder how it's possible to get user attributes without explicitly hardcoding sub value to get all other related attributes? do I need to decode JWT Cognito token in frontend and use it in the lambda to determine the correct user and retrieve the related attributes?

here is my lambda in Node.JS:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

var cog = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

var filter = "sub = \"" + "UserSUB" + "\"";
var req = {
    "Filter": filter,
    "UserPoolId": 'POOL here',
};

cog.listUsers(req, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        if (data.Users.length === 1){ 
            var user = data.Users[0];
            var attributes = data.Users[0].Attributes;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(attributes));
        } else {
            console.log("error.");
        }
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way to do this depends on whether you want to use API Gateway or not (It will make things simpler IMHO).

If you **don't** want to use APIG, and you are calling the lambda directly using temporary credentials, then you should pass the entire ID token and have the lambda do all of the validation and decoding (probably using a third party library for JWTs). It's not safe to do it in the frontend as that would mean you have a lambda that blindly accepts the attributes as facts from the frontend, and a malicious user could change them if they wanted.

If you are using API Gateway to put lambdas behind an API then I would create a cognito authorizer based on the User Pool, create a resource/method and configure it to use the authorizer, and enable `Use Lambda Proxy Integration` for the `Integration Request`. All the token's claims enabled for the client will be passed through on `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims` so long as it's valid.

There are some AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html), although this does not use proxy integration. If you use proxy integration then you can skip 6b as the APIG will set the values for you. This is described in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574425/get-cognito-user-pool-identity-in-lambda-function/50634753#50634753).